# Sum values from 2 tables and subtract it to each other

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables, ord_tbl and pay_tbl. o_tbl with these data.

ord_tbl

```
invoice | emp_id | prod_id | amount
123     | 101    | 1       | 1000
123     | 101    | 2       | 500
123     | 101    | 3       | 500
124     | 101    | 2       | 300
125     | 102    | 3       | 200
```

pay_tbl

```
invoice | new_invoice | amount
123     | 321         | 300
123     | 322         | 200
124     | 323         | 300
125     | 324         | 100
```

I would like the selection statement to give me this result

```
invoice | emp_id | orig_amt | balance | status
123     | 101    | 2000     | 1500    | unsettled
```

The invoice that has  0 balance will not be included anymore. I know that I have to use the join and sub queries here but I don't even know how to start it! For me, as a beginner, this is very complex already. This is what I tried so far...

```
SELECT 
  ord_tbl.invoice,
  SUM(ord_tbl.amount) As 'origAmt',
  SUM(pay_tbl.amount) As 'payAmt', 
  origAmt - payAmt As 'bal' 
FROM 
  ord_tbl 
  INNER JOIN pay_tbl 
    ON ord_tbl.invoice = pay_tbl.invoice 
WHERE 
  ord_tbl.emp_id = @emp_id AND 
  bal != 0 
GROUP BY 
  ord_tbl.invoice
```

Comment: Aliases are not visible in the same statement,use SUM.. - SUM...

Comment: SELECT ord_tbl.invoice, SUM(ord_tbl.amount) As 'origAmt', SUM(pay_tbl.amount) As 'payAmt', 
(SUM(ord_tbl.amount) -  SUM(pay_tbl.amount)) As 'bal' FROM ord_tbl 
INNER JOIN pay_tbl ON ord_tbl.invoice = pay_tbl.invoice 
WHERE ord_tbl.emp_id = '101'
GROUP BY ord_tbl.invoice

Comment: This gives me the wrong values... What I get for orig_amt is 4000 and the balance is 1500 and I can't get rid of the values that results to 0 when the balance is 0.

Comment: So you want to get rid of results where balance is 0?

Comment: That and the table result that I have created in my initial question.              I would like the selection statement to give me this result.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepare your data joining on a non unique field will lead to a cross JOIN,that`s why you get 4000

```
;WITH CTE as
(SELECT ot.invoice,MAX(ot.emp_id) as emp_id,SUM(ot.amount) as origAmt FROM ord_tbl ot GROUP BY ot.invoice),
CTE2 as
( SELECT pt.invoice,SUM(pt.ammount) as payAmt FROM pay_tbl pt GROUP BY pt.invoice)
SELECT CTE.invoice,CTE.emp_id,CTE.origAmt,CTE.origAmt-NULLIF(CTE2.payAmt,0) as bal,'unsettled' as status
FROM
CTE LEFT JOIN CTE2 ON CTE.invoice=CTE2.invoice 
AND CTE.emp_id=101 AND CTE.origAmt-NULLIF(CTE2.payAmt,0)>0
```

Comment: Wow! This looks complicated but I'll test this one.

Comment: This is great Mihai. The only problem is, when there is no payment yet in the pay_tbl for the invoice in the ord_tbl, that invoice is not listed in the result. Could you help a little more please.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 Just change the INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN,edited my answer

Comment: Sorry Mihai I changed my JOIN to LEFT JOIN but I still don't get the values that has no payment.  ;WITH CTE as
(SELECT ot.invoice,MAX(ot.emp_id) as emp_id,SUM(ot.amount) as origAmt FROM ord_tbl ot GROUP BY ot.invoice),
CTE2 as
( SELECT pt.invoice,SUM(pt.amount) as payAmt FROM pay_tbl pt GROUP BY pt.invoice)
SELECT CTE.invoice,CTE.emp_id,CTE.origAmt,CTE.origAmt-CTE2.payAmt as bal,'unsettled' as status
FROM
CTE LEFT JOIN CTE2 ON CTE.invoice=CTE2.invoice 
WHERE CTE.emp_id=101 AND CTE.origAmt-CTE2.payAmt>0

Comment: @Ibanez1408 If you want all values,remove the WHERE condition

Comment: It's not that. The emp_id is still 101. What is happening is when there is no record of the invoice in the ord_tbl in the pay_tbl, that invoice is not seen in the result table but if I place a record in the pay_tbl with amount as 0, then it shows in the result table.

Comment: I think when there is no record in the pay_tbl to compare it to the ord_tbl, the invoice record is skipped thus it does not show up in the result table. A little more Mihai please.

Comment: I got it Mihail! The last suggestion you gave "CTE.origAmt-NULLIF(CTE2.payAmt,0)>0" didn't solve the issue too but I came up with something. I know that it isn't great but it's the best I could come up with. I just added "CTE.origAmt-CTE2.payAmt>0 OR CTE2.payAmt IS NULL" and I can see ALL the invoices even without pay_tbl yet but the column says NULL.THANK YOU! But if you have something better please suggest some more.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 I should have thought about IS NULL since its a LEFT JOIN,glad you pieced the final puzzle.